# How am I messing up these modules?

Tags: module, rust, libraries, rust-crates

I'm trying to create a crate that has a library and one or more binaries. I've looked at [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946646/rust-package-with-both-a-library-and-a-binary) and [the Rust book section on crates and modules](http://rust.dev/book/crates-and-modules.html) but am still running into errors when I try and compile.

I've included the relevant sections of each file (I think).

../cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "plotmote"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Camden Narzt <my@nice.email>"]

[lib]
name = "lib_plotMote"
path = "src/lib.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "plotMote"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

lib.rs:

```
pub mod lib_plotMote;
```

lib_plotMote/mod.rs:

```
pub mod LogstreamProcessor;
```

lib_plotMote/LogstreamProcessor.rs:

```
pub struct LogstreamProcessor {
```

main.rs:

```
extern crate lib_plotMote;
use lib_plotMote::LogStreamProcessor;
```

error:

```
cargo build
   Compiling plotmote v0.1.0 (file:///Users/camdennarzt/Developer/Rust/plotmote)
main.rs:6:5: 6:37 error: unresolved import `lib_plotMote::LogStreamProcessor`. There is no `LogStreamProcessor` in `lib_plotMote` [E0432]
```

Comment: `LogStreamProcessor` is not the same as `LogstreamProcessor` (`s` has different case). Also better follow the Rust code style with lowercase names for modules. https://doc.rust-lang.org/style/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
use lib_plotMote::lib_plotMote::LogStreamProcessor;
```

The first `lib_plotMote` comes from `extern crate`, and the second one comes from the module you have defined in the library crate:

```
pub mod lib_plotMote;
```

Therefore, the library crate contains one module which, coincidentally, has the same name as the crate itself.

Also, as @starblue has noticed, you have case mismatch in the declaration site of the structure (`LogstreamProcessor`) and its use site (`LogStreamProcessor`). This should also be fixed.

As as side note, I suggest you to follow the idiomatic naming convention and avoid camelCase in module/crate names.