# How can I build multiple binaries with Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'd like to make a project with a `daemon` and a `client`, connecting through a unix socket.

A `client` and a `daemon` requires two binaries, so how do I tell `Cargo` to build two targets from two different sources?

To add a bit of fantasy, I'd like to have a `library` for the main part of the `daemon`, and just have a binary to wrap around it and communicate through sockets.

So, we have this kind of tree architecture:

```
├── Cargo.toml
├── target
|   └── debug
|       ├── daemon
│       └── client
└── src
    ├── daemon
    │   ├── bin
    │   │   └── main.rs
    │   └── lib
    │       └── lib.rs
    └── client
        └── bin
            └── main.rs
```

I could make one executable which manages both concerns, but that's not what I want to do, unless it's very good practice.

Comment: Highly relevant: [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26946646/155423).

Comment: In complement of [Dognert's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604010/how-can-i-build-multiple-binaries-with-cargo/36604610#36604610) answer, they answer all the questions I got. Thank you a lot!

Comment: this seems to be the relevant issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8294

Answer (score 347, accepted):

You can specify multiple binaries using `[[bin]]`, as mentioned in the [Cargo Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#binaries)

```toml
[[bin]]
name = "daemon"
path = "src/daemon/bin/main.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "client"
path = "src/client/bin/main.rs"
```

You can run individual binaries with the `cargo run` command with the `--bin <bin-name>` option.

Tip: If you instead put these files in `src/bin/daemon.rs` and `src/bin/client.rs`, you'll get two executables named `daemon` and `client` as Cargo compiles all files in `src/bin` into executables with the same name automatically. You need to specify names and paths like in the snippet above only if you don't follow this convention.

Comment: @AngelAngel you want to customize the output path? By default it'll be stored in `target/debug/$name` where `$name` is the `name` you specify in Cargo.toml.

Comment: I just wondered if you could say where to install a copy of the binary elsewhere other than the default. A copy in $name and another copy in another path. Not that it is trivial, just curious, thanks for your time.

Comment: @AngelAngel I think you're looking for the `cargo install` command. Try reading the output of `cargo help install`.

Comment: This doesn't work if one of the `[[bin]]`s uses `required-features`. For that it seems like `cargo workspace` is the only solution?

Comment: How do you specify the default binary? ie say client should be default

Comment: @AnatolyBugakov you mean setting the default for `cargo run`? See https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-default-run-field.

Comment: It is worth noting that the line 'default-run = "a"' can be added under package in Cargo.toml to specify a default to run when using the form described in this answer.

Comment: @Dogbert can these have different dependencies? I'd like to not include all deps of all bins into all bins

Comment: [Solution for shared files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737786/correct-place-for-private-module-to-be-used-by-multiple-executables)

Comment: So when you run `cargo build`, which one would it build? Daemon or client?

Answer (score 84):

Another way is to use [the workspace feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section). This will provide more flexibility due to the fact that we can have more than one library. Example project structure:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── cli
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── core
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
├── daemon
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── gui
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
└── rpc
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── lib.rs
```

Contents of the root `Cargo.toml`:

```
[workspace]
members = ["cli", "core", "daemon", "gui", "rpc"]
```

Comment: I could not get this to work. I had to move the binary rust source in the src/ folder and specify another target in `[[bin]]`. Could you give more details about what you did to get this to work?

I was getting the following error:

`use ::engine::RuleEngine;`
`could not find engine in {{root}}`

Comment: @KennyBambridge I have not worked on Rust for awhile. IIRC when I have created this answer I tried on my local machine and it work as intended.

Comment: @KennyBambridge You do have to add crates in other workspaces as dependencies in the Cargo.toml where you want to use them.

Comment: I saw filecoin use this code structure: https://github.com/filecoin-project/rust-fil-proofs

Comment: I got it working, but I ended up referring to different Workspace docs, i.e. the one in the Rust book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html

Comment: Here's an example of such approach: https://github.com/JohnScience/two-bins-wp-example

However, feature unification can cause troubles.

Answer (score 4):

Another format could be to replicate what the [Crates.io source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io/tree/master/src) has done, if you have a massive project, something like:

Main Library in src, with a Bin folder with your executables.
Then make calls to your main library crate from your executables.

That way you library is centralized so easier to find things as it's cached.