# Correct place for private module to be used by multiple executables

Tags: rust, include, rust-cargo

Two executables' sources, `foo.rs` and `bar.rs`, are located in `src/bin`.

Private common functionality exists in `src/bin/common.rs`.

`foo.rs` and `bar.rs` include this functionality with:

```
mod common;
use common::{Bish, Bash, Bosh};
```

This works, but `src/bin/common.rs` doesn't feel like the right path for something which isn't going to be built into an executable.

Moving `common.rs` to `src` or `src/lib` stops `foo.rs` and `bar.rs` from seeing it.

Where should I put `common.rs` and how do I then import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach to store shared parts at lib.rs and use these in binaries. Its usage, though, is a bit different than simply *mod + use*. In fact, library is a separate crate, so you need to access it via crate name (defined in Cargo.toml).

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "crate-name"
# ... the rest
```

src/bin/foo.rs:

```rust
fn main() {
  crate_name::fun();
}
```

src/lib.rs:

```rust
pub fn fun() {}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it sends the Rust Language Server a little crazy.  The code compiles, but RLS complains: `unresolved import 'crate-name'
use of undeclared type or module 'crate-name' rustc (E0432)
foo.rs(10, 5): use of undeclared type or module 'crate-name'`

Comment: RLS quite a strange beast. I think [rust-analyzer](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer) is much better choice know, try it out.

Comment: Many thanks.  Rebooting fixed the RLS issue.  VSCode extension warns that rust-analyzer is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
example
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── bin
    │   ├── bar.rs
    │   └── foo.rs
    ├── common.rs
    └── lib.rs
```

`foo.rs` and `bar.rs`:

```
#[path = "../common.rs"]
mod common;
use common::{Bish, Bash, Bosh};
```

also see: [How can I use a module from outside the src folder in a binary project, such as for integration tests or benchmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998085/how-can-i-use-a-module-from-outside-the-src-folder-in-a-binary-project-such-as)

Comment: Can you explain what the `#[path = "../common.rs"]` means? I've never seen that. Does it only apply to the next statement or do you need to be careful with other imports? Would be great if you could explain your answer a bit more.

Comment: The link you provided actually recommends strongly against using the solution you suggest here.

Comment: [Module Source Filenames](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#module-source-filenames)

Comment: This is appropriate when the specified module does not depend on other project files.