# Dead code warning with multiple binaries?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-clippy

I noticed that in order for a piece of code to not be classified as dead, it has to be reachable from all binaries. Example:

Cargo.toml:

```toml
[[bin]]
name = "main_one"
path = "src/main_one.rs"
[[bin]]
name = "main_two"
path = "src/main_two.rs"
```

main_one.rs:

```rust
mod utils;
fn main() {
    print!("Hello, ");
    utils::function_in_question();
}
```

main_two.rs:

```rust
mod utils;
fn main() {
    print!("Hello, ");
    // utils::function_in_question();
}
```

utils.rs:

```rust
pub fn function_in_question() {
    println!("world!");
}
```

This reports `function_in_question` as dead code, even though it's reachable from `main_one.rs`. Uncommenting it fixes this issue. Works also if it's present only in `main_two.rs`.

Although there is some rationale behind this behavior, it is annyoing to have VSCode complain about this all the time + the output of Clippy is spammed by these warnings. Is there a solution to at least surpress dead code detection globally? Restructuring the whole project with cargo workspaces should be avoided.

Comment: To silence warnings globally refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877389/2766908).

Comment: @pretzelhammer Ok, adding #![allow(dead_code)] to the top of every binary entry point file silences the warnings. I however agree with your comment on this not being a solid solution.

Comment: Add `#![allow(dead_code]` to the top of your main source files, not `Cargo.toml`. And yes, as I said earlier, I'd still like to see an answer with a proper solution to this problem, as globally silencing an otherwise useful warning just avoids the problem (and creates another in the process).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens because you're not compiling `utils.rs` just once -- you're compiling it twice, first as part of `main_one` and then as part of `main_two`.

The pattern I am familiar with is to put common items into `lib.rs`, which is by default compiled into a library crate with the same name as your project. Then, instead of including them in each binary with `mod`, just use the library crate.

```yaml
# Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "my_crate" # <- will be the name of the library crate
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]

# No need for [[bin]] sections if you put the binary sources in src/bin
```

```
// src/lib.rs
pub fn function_in_question() {
    println!("world!");
}
```

```
// src/bin/main_one.rs
fn main() {
    print!("Hello, ");
    my_crate::function_in_question();
}
```

```
// src/bin/main_two.rs
fn main() {
    print!("Hello, ");
    // my_crate::function_in_question();
}
```

The library crate will be compiled only once, and because `function_in_question` is part of the crate's public API, you will see no dead code warnings.

Note that you do not need `[[bin]]` sections in `Cargo.toml` if you put the binary files in `src/bin`; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604010/how-can-i-build-multiple-binaries-with-cargo) for more.

Comment: I should have stumbled upon this a while ago, now I have to go in all my project and improve the structure :)

Comment: Won't putting everything into a library crate silence any useful dead_code warnings?   I don't want the warning to go away completely, I want to only fire if the function is unused by both main_one and main_two.