# Rust Cargo does not automatically compile depended project in workspace

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a workspace with two projects as below

```
workspace/
├─ project-a/
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ Cargo.toml
├─ project-b/
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ Cargo.toml
├─ Cargo.toml
```

Project b depends on project a, it launches the binary file generated by project a with `std::process::Command`.

In `/workspace/project-b/Cargo.toml`, I set the dependencies as below.

```
[dependencies]
project-a = { path = "../project-a" }


[dev-dependencies]
project-a = { path = "../project-a" }
```

And in `/workspace/Cargo.toml`, I set default entry to be project b.

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "project-a",
    "project-b",
]
default-members=["project-b"]
```

It works well if I run `cargo run` in `/workspace`` directory,  project-b can successfully launches project-a as a child process.

But when I modify the code in /workspace/project-a``, `cargo run` in `/workspace` directory will not compile the updated code. Still I need enter `/workspace/project-a/` directory and execute `cargo run` once more.

How can I make `cargo run` in `/workspace`` directory automatically compiles its dependencies?

Comment: Based on these issues: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/7971, https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/872, it looks like cargo does not support this at this time. However, if it is not essential for `project-a` and `project-b` to be separate crates, you may be able to use this solution instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604010/how-can-i-build-multiple-binaries-with-cargo