# Problem trying to convert a rust project into a rust workspace

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a rust workspace, having multiple binaries to build from same project

Actually I prepared structure as follow

[image]

Where external Cargo.tml contains only

```
[workspace]
members = ["itris-console", "autolearn" ]
```

And itris-console/Cargo.toml contains

```
[package]
name = "itris"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
arr_macro = "0.1.3"

[[bin]]
name = "itris"
path = "src/main.rs"
test = false
bench = false
```

And autolearn/Cargo.toml is

```
[package]
name = "autolearn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

I am trying to build it all from project root (the itris2 directory)

I got this problem

```
cargo build
error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `C:\Progetti\rust\itris2\itris-console`

Caused by:
  failed to read `C:\Progetti\rust\itris2\itris-console\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato. (os error 3)
```

I consulted what follows but I cannot make it works

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#binaries
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57630418/1055279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The itris-console and autolearn directories should not be in a src directory.

Currently path to your itris-console directory is `C:\Progetti\rust\itris2\src\itris-console` while it should be `C:\Progetti\rust\itris2\itris-console`. Remove the unnecessary `src` directory from the path and you are almost good to go.

Since you are on windows you also need to use escaped forward-slashes while defining the path to the bin in `itris-console\Cargo.toml` (`"src/main.rs"` -> `"src\\main.rs"`).