# How to move tests into a separate file for binaries in Rust's Cargo?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

I created a new binary using Cargo:

```
cargo new my_binary --bin
```

A function in `my_binary/src/main.rs` can be used for a test:

```
fn function_from_main() {
    println!("Test OK");
}

#[test]
fn my_test() {
    function_from_main();
}
```

And `cargo test -- --nocapture` runs the test as expected.

What's the most straightforward way to move this test into a separate file, (keeping `function_from_main` in `my_binary/src/main.rs`)?

I tried to do this but am not sure how to make `my_test` call `function_from_main` from a separate file.

Answer (score 82):

*The Rust Programming Language* has [a chapter dedicated to testing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-00-testing.html) which you should read to gain a baseline understanding.

---

It's common to put unit tests (tests that are more allowed to access internals of your code) into a `test` module in each specific file:

```
fn function_from_main() {
    println!("Test OK");
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn my_test() {
        function_from_main();
    }
}
```

Modules can be moved to new files, although this is uncommon for the unit test module:

**main.rs**

```
fn function_from_main() {
    println!("Test OK");
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test;
```

**test.rs**

```
use super::*;

#[test]
fn my_test() {
    function_from_main();
}
```

See [Separating Modules into Different Files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html) for detailed information on how files and modules map to each other.

---

The more common case for tests in a separate file are integration tests. These are also covered in the book by a [section devoted to tests outside of the crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#integration-tests). These types of tests are well-suited for exercising the code **as a consumer of your code would**.

That section of the documentation includes an introductory example and descriptive text:

> We create a *tests* directory at the top level of our project directory,
> next to *src*. Cargo knows to look for integration test files in this
> directory. We can then make as many test files as we want to in this
> directory, and Cargo will compile each of the files as an individual
> crate.
>
> Let’s create an integration test. With the code in Listing 11-12 still
> in the *src/lib.rs* file, make a *tests* directory, create a new file
> named *tests/integration_test.rs*, and enter the code in Listing 11-13:
>
> Filename: tests/integration_test.rs
>
> ```
> use adder;
>
> #[test]
> fn it_adds_two() {
>     assert_eq!(4, adder::add_two(2));
> }
> ```
>
> **Listing 11-13: An integration test of a function in the adder crate**
>
> We’ve added `use adder` at the top of the code, which we didn’t need in
> the unit tests. The reason is that each test in the tests directory is
> a separate crate, so we need to bring our library into each test
> crate’s scope.

Note that the function is called as `adder::add_two`. Further details about Rust's module system can be found in the [Packages, Crates, and Modules chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-00-packages-crates-and-modules.html).

Since these tests exercise your crate as a user would, if you want to test a *binary*, you should be **executing the binary**. Crates like [assert_cmd](https://crates.io/crates/assert_cmd) can help reduce the pain of this type of test.

In other cases, you should break your large binary into a large library and a small binary. You can then write integration tests for the public API of your library.

See also:

- [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946646/155423)

Comment: How to write the integration tests (the tests inside to `tests` directory) for an *executable* (not *lib*)? `extern crate <executable>` does not work then.

Comment: @Nawaz if you are performing *integration* tests of an executable, you drive it as the user would: by running the built command via something like `std::process::Command`. Otherwise you are talking about unit tests.

Comment: Using a debugger with an integration test testing a bin by spawning a separate process is a suboptimal developer experience. :-(

Comment: @Shepmaster, I am not able to understand the difference between your answer and @mmai answer. Could you explain why naming the tests file `test.rs` works and naming it `foo_test.rs` does not work without path?

Comment: @TamilVendhanKanagarasu because the language expects module *filenames* to match the module *names*. When you go outside the convention, how would the compiler know which file to look in? I would generally discourage people from using the `#[path]` attribute except in *very specific* cases (and this is not one of them).

Answer (score 24):

If you have a module *foo.rs* and want to place your unit tests next to it in a file called *foo_test.rs*, you'll find that this isn't always the place that Rust will look for a child module.

You can use the `#[path]` attribute to specify the location of the file corresponding to the module:

```
#[cfg(test)]
#[path = "./foo_test.rs"]
mod foo_test;
```

This is explained in the blog post [Better location for unit tests in Rust](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-unit-test-placement.html).

Comment: Why do you want to go out of your way to put files in non-idiomatic locations? Place it as `foo.rs` and `foo/tests.rs`, just like every other module.

Comment: No irritation here as I don't have to work on your code! I just find the going to be much smoother if I follow the idioms of the language, not trying to carry along all of the baggage from each previous language.

Comment: Why is `#[path]` needed? Most people would reach for `mod foo_test` because it looks the same as what was in `lib.rs`, but they get a `file not found error`. This happens because when you use `mod foo`, all code in `foo.rs` is now in the scope of the module `foo` - which effects where `mod` searches in. So while in the scope of module `foo`, `mod foo_test` looks for `src/foo/mod_test.rs`, and `src/foo/mod_test/mod.rs`. A little hard to wrap the head around. Also, in `foo_test.rs` you then write `use super::my_func` to access members of `foo.rs` (the `foo` module).

Comment: @Shepmaster i think this is a pretty cool possibility to allow ppl to keep the unit tests separately from its source, to prevent polluting the source. Actually this is the first a few questions i searched after i reading the rust book, i could seriously black rust without this possibility, hardly believe messing the unit tests and source together is a more maintainable way

Comment: From the rust book: "The convention is to create a module named tests in each file to contain the test functions and to annotate the module with cfg(test)."

I would simply follow the "convention."  Non-idiomatic practices make it harder for someone else who gets into your code.

Comment: It's nice that Rust is batteries-included for tests, but it doesn't but follows conventions of all the other test frameworks. It's good practice to separate code into different files to aid in organization; this holds for tests as well. Personally I want to be able to page up/page down through the file and see key points, I don't want to have to read lines which are not relevant to helping me understand functioning of the module - especially when my tests make up more than half of the lines. To me this is worth breaking from idiomatic Rust use; ymmv.

Answer (score 3):

You're right; `function_from_main` is inaccessible outside of `main.rs`.

You need to create an `src/lib.rs` and move the functions you want to test piecemeal.  Then you'll be able to use `extern crate my_binary;` from your test module, and have your functions appear under the `my_binary` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

I do believe you should follow the advice of reading the Rust book chapter on testing, however, that still won't quite answer your question, *how to separate test and source files*.

So say you have a `lib.rs` source file and wanted a `test_lib.rs` file. To do this all you need is:

In your `lib.rs`:

```
mod test_lib;

// rest of source
```

Then in your `test_lib.rs`:

```
#[cfg(test)]
use super::*;

#[test]
fn test1() {
    // test logic 
}

// more tests
```

Then, both you and `cargo test` should be happy.

Answer (score 0):

To embellish* @mmai's answer:

```
#[rustfmt::skip]
#[cfg(test)]
#[path = "./foo_test.rs"]
mod foo_test;
```

`cargo fmt` seems to be unhappy following the path to the new test file. If anyone has a better solution I'd be happy to hear it, because I wish `cargo fmt` would format my test files too!

*Sorry: I'd add this just as a comment on the existing answer but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer adds to mmai's answer. Also, please don't ask follow-up questions in answers. That's a discussion forum style, which is not appropriate for the Q&A format on this site.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30751950)