# How can I use a module from outside the src folder in a binary project, such as for integration tests or benchmarks?

Tags: rust

My project's path structure is as follows:

```
demo
├── benches
│   └── crypto_bench.rs
├── src
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── crypto.rs
├── Cargo.lock
└── Cargo.toml
```

`crypto.rs` contains a struct `Crypto` with implementation.
`crypto.rs` is referred to from `main.rs` using `mod crypto;`

How can I use `crypto.rs` from `crypto_bench.rs` inside the benches folder?

I have tried all kinds of variations of `extern crate`, `mod`, `super` and `use`.
All examples I could find online are for library projects with a `lib.rs` and those "imports" don't work when using a project with a `main.rs` file.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here's a literal answer, but **don't actually use this**!

```
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

#[path = "../src/foo.rs"] // Here
mod foo;

#[bench]
fn bencher(_: &mut test::Bencher) {
    println!("{:?}", foo::Thang);
}
```

In fact, it's very likely that this won't work because your code in `foo.rs` needs supporting code from other files that won't be included.

---

Instead of doing this, *just create a library*. You have the pure definition of a library - a piece of code that wants to be used in two different executables. You don't have to give up having an executable or even create separate directories (see [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946646/155423)), but creating reusable code is a key component of making *good* code.

Your end state would look something like:

```
demo
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── benches
│   └── crypto_bench.rs
├── benchmarks
└── src
    ├── bin
    │   └── main.rs
    ├── crypto.rs
    └── lib.rs
```

Move the reusable code to a library:

**src/lib.rs**

```
pub mod crypto;
```

**src/crypto.rs**

```
pub struct Crypto;
impl Crypto {
    pub fn secret() {}
}
```

Then import your library from the benchmark and the binary:

**benches/crypto_bench.rs**

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

use demo::crypto::Crypto;
use test::Bencher;

#[bench]
fn speedy(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| Crypto::secret());
}
```

**src/bin/main.rs**

```
use demo::crypto::Crypto;

fn main() {
    Crypto::secret();
    eprintln!("Did the secret thing!");
}
```

You can then run it in different ways:

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling demo v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/example)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.51s

$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/main`
Did the secret thing!

$ cargo +nightly bench
   Compiling demo v0.1.0 (/private/tmp/example)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.70s
     Running target/release/deps/my_benchmark-5c9c5716763252a0

running 1 test
test speedy ... bench:           1 ns/iter (+/- 0)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 1 measured; 0 filtered out
```

See also:

- [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946646/155423)
- [What is an idiomatic way to have shared utility functions for integration tests and benchmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44539729/155423)
- [Can I make an object public for integration tests and/or benchmarks only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47698194/155423)
- [Cannot import a module in an integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46867652/155423)

Comment: To add onto this answer, if your library crate-type is exclusively a "cdylib", you'll get a "can't find create for `demo`" compilation error - see https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6659.

To get integration tests / benchmarks working, you'll want add "(r)lib" to the list of crate-type.