# How do I tell Cargo to run files from a directory other than "src"?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a front-end project that has a lot of stuff in `src` folder, and I have the opportunity to also use Rust on the server side. All my Rust server files are in the `server` folder; how can I tell Cargo to run `./server/app.rs`?

Comment: You're probably better off just having your entire Cargo project inside the `server` folder.

Comment: this may be helpful http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#configuring-a-target

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you are *probably* better off just moving all of your code into the "server" directory. If you don't, you are going to be swimming uphill against defaults, which is not usually a great idea.

That being said, you *can* [specify the path to the binary or library in your Cargo.toml](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#configuring-a-target):

```
[[bin]]
name = "quux"
path = "server/main.rs"
```

```
[lib]
name = "quux"
path = "server/lib.rs"
```

See also:

- [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946646/155423)