# How to import a module from a directory outside of the `src` directory?

Tags: module, rust, rust-cargo

I'm stuck when learning how to access a module. I'm trying to insert a folder other than `src` into `src`. It's not working and it gives me an error. Here this is my project tree.

```
$ Project1
.
|-- src
|       |-- main.rs
|   |--FolderinSrcFolder 
|       |--folderinsrcmodule.rs    
|
|--anothersrc
|   |--mod.rs
|
|-- rootmodule.rs
|-- Cargo.toml
|-- Cargo.lock
```

How can I access `anothersrc/mod.rs` `src/main.rs`? How can I access `rootmodule.rs` from `src/main.rs`?

I already read the Rust documentation.

Comment: It sounds like you could use workspaces. https://learning-rust.github.io/docs/d5.workspaces.html

Comment: Link seems to be: https://learning-rust.github.io/docs/workspaces/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Idiomatic solution

**Don't**. Put all of your source code into the  `src` directory. You could also create another crate with its own `src` directory. Don't fight these idioms and conventions, it's simply not worth it.

See also:

- [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946646/155423)

## Literal solution

This directly answers your question, but I strongly recommend that you *don't actually use this*!

**Layout**

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── bad_location.rs
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

**src/main.rs**

```
#[path = "../bad_location.rs"]
mod bad_location;

fn main() {
    println!("Was this a bad idea? {}", bad_location::dont_do_this());
}
```

**badlocation.rs**

```
pub fn dont_do_this() -> bool {
    true
}
```

The key is the `#[path]` annotation.

See also:

- [How can I use a module from outside the src folder in a binary project, such as for integration tests or benchmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43998085/155423)
- [How do I tell Cargo to run files from a directory other than "src"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47649318/155423)
- [How do I import from a sibling module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30677258/155423)