# How do I use code from a library's example in the library itself?

Tags: module, rust

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│    └── model.rs
└── examples
    └── client
           └──mod.rs
```

I want to use a struct called `Client` that exists in `examples > client > mod.rs` in my `model.rs` file. My package name is `CratesTest` in the `Cargo.toml`.

I tried this in my `model.rs`:

```
extern crate CratesTest;

fn main() {
    CratesTest::Client::new(/*snip*/)
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Client` in `CratesTest`
let client = CratesTest::Client::new(...
                         ^^^^^^ could not find `Client` in `CratesTest`
```

I also tried using `mod client;` but it doesn't bring it into scope.

Comment: I'd say there's an inversion of dependency here: it's reasonable for your examples to depend on your library, but why would your library depends on the examples?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#examples): "Files located under examples are example **uses** of the functionality provided by the library" (emphasy mine). Examples use the library, not the reverse.

Comment: @Jmb I don't think there's another answer that what you said. You should transmute your comment into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say there's an inversion of dependency here: it's reasonable for your examples to depend on your library, but why would your library depend on the examples? As pointed out by Denys Séguret, [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#examples) states:

> Files located under examples are example **uses** of the functionality provided by the library

so examples use the library, not the reverse.

Comment: See also [How can I use a module from outside the src folder in a binary project, such as for integration tests or benchmarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44002428/155423); [How to import a module from a directory outside of the `src` directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58715429/155423).