# How to access functions from the main crate when writing integration tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, rust-cargo

When creating a project with a test like so:

```
cargo init --bin projectname
mkdir projectname/tests
echo "extern crate projectname;" > projectname/tests/test.rs
cd projectname/
cargo build
```

I get this error when testing:

```
cargo test
   Compiling projectname v0.1.0 (file:///home/username/Lab/projectname)
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `projectname`
 --> tests/test.rs:1:1
  |
1 | extern crate projectname;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

How can I access the functions in ´projectname/src/main.rs´ from `projectname/tests/test.rs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I access functions in ´projectname/src/main.rs´ from projectname/tests/test.rs?

**You cannot.**

---

A binary cannot be used a an external crate (the same way as you can't use a ELF binary as a shared object/library)

You just have to change your initialisation to

```
cargo init --lib projectname
```

or rename your `main.rs` to `lib.rs`

If you really want to stick with a main, you may look at [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946646/rust-package-with-both-a-library-and-a-binary).