# Rust modules confusion when there is main.rs and lib.rs

Tags: module, rust

I have 4 files:

**`main.rs`**

```
mod bar;

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

**`lib.rs`**

```
pub mod foo;
pub mod bar;
```

**`foo.rs`**

```
pub fn say_foo() {

}
```

**`bar.rs`**

```
use crate::foo;

fn bar() {
    foo::say_foo();
}
```

When I run `cargo run` I get an error saying:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::foo`
 --> src/bar.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use crate::foo;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^ no `foo` in the root
```

Could someone explain to me how to fix this? A bit more broadly: how does module lookup work when there's a `main.rs` and a `lib.rs`?

Edit: Adding `mod foo` to `main.rs` fixes the issue. But I don't understand this -- I was under the impression the `lib.rs` was the place that "exposed" all of my modules? Why do I have to declare the module in `main.rs` as well?

My `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "hello-world"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["me@mgail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

Comment: What do you want to do? If bar needs foo to work, how do you want to use bar in the binary without foo?

Comment: What's in your `Cargo.toml`? Do you have [a library and a binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946646/rust-package-with-both-a-library-and-a-binary) in one project or not? Seems that you're mixing things together a bit.

Answer (score 353):

Let's start from the beginning. Look at the [Package Layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) chapter in [The Cargo Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/index.html). As you can see, your package can contain lot of stuff:

- a binary (something you can run) or multiple binaries,
- a single library (shared code),
- example(s),
- benchmark(s),
- integration tests.

## Package layout

Not all of the possibilities are listed here, just the binary / library combinations.

### A binary

This is an example of a package with single binary. Entry point is the `main` function in the `src/main.rs`.

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "hallo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
```

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hallo, Rust here!")
}
```

```sh
$ cargo run
Hallo, Rust here!
```

### A library

This is an example of a package with a library. Libraries don't have entry points, you can't run them. They're used for functionality sharing.

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "hallo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
```

`src/lib.rs`:

```rust
pub fn foo() {
    println!("Hallo, Rust library here!")
}
```

```sh
$ cargo run
error: a bin target must be available for `cargo run`
```

Do you see anything in the `Cargo.toml` file about a binary or a library? No. The reason is that I've followed the [Package Layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) and the `cargo` knows where to look for things.

### A binary and a library

This is an example of a package with a binary and a library.

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "hallo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
```

`src/lib.rs`:

```rust
pub const GREETING: &'static str = "Hallo, Rust library here!";
```

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
use hallo::GREETING;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", GREETING);
}
```

Same question, do you see anything in the `Cargo.toml` file about a binary or a library? No.

This package contains two things:

- a binary (root `src/main.rs`, entry point `src/main.rs::main`),
- a library (root `src/lib.rs`, shared code).

A library can be referenced from the binary via `use hallo::...` where the `hallo` is this package name (`Cargo.toml` -> `[package]` -> `name`).

## Your problem

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "hallo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
```

### Same package layout

#### A library part

`src/lib.rs`:

```rust
pub mod bar;
pub mod foo;
```

`src/foo.rs`:

```rust
pub fn say_foo() {
    println!("Foo");
}
```

`src/bar.rs`:

```rust
use crate::foo;

pub fn bar() {
    foo::say_foo();
}
```

`crate` refers to `src/lib.rs`, because we're in the context of our library here.

Treat it as a standalone unit and refer to it via `use hallo::...;` from the outside world.

#### A binary part

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
use hallo::bar::bar;

fn main() {
    bar();
}
```

Here we're just using our library.

### Without a library

Same code, but `lib.rs` was renamed to `utils.rs` and `(foo|bar).rs` files were moved to the `src/utils/` folder.

`src/utils.rs`:

```rust
pub mod bar;
pub mod foo;
```

`src/utils/foo.rs`:

```rust
pub fn say_foo() {
    println!("Foo");
}
```

`src/utils/bar.rs`:

```rust
use super::foo;
// or use crate::utils::foo;

pub fn bar() {
    foo::say_foo();
}
```

We can use `crate` here as well, but because we're in the context of our binary, the path differs.

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
use utils::bar::bar;

mod utils;

fn main() {
    bar();
}
```

Here we just declared another module (`utils`) and we're using it.

## Summary

`Cargo.toml` content:

```
[package]
name = "hallo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
```

If there's a `src/main.rs` file, you're basically saying this:

```
[package]
name = "hallo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[[bin]]
name = "hallo"
src = "src/main.rs"
```

If there's a `src/lib.rs` file, you're basically saying this:

```
[package]
name = "hallo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "hallo"
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

If there're both of them, you're basically saying this:

```
[package]
name = "hallo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[[bin]]
name = "hallo"
path = "src/main.rs"

[lib]
name = "hallo"
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

## Documentation

- [Package Layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html)
- [The Manifest Format](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html)
- [Managing Growing Projects with Packages, Crates, and Modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html)

Comment: "`crate` refers to `src/lib.rs`, because we're in the context of our library here." But hang on though, aren't `foo` and `bar` both in the same crate context, since they're both modules within `lib.rs`? Why would `bar` have to refer to `foo` as if it were external?

Comment: You mean `use crate::foo;`? Why do you think it's an external reference, it's not. The `crate` keyword refers to [the current crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html#the-crate-keyword-refers-to-the-current-crate), which is the library itself. You can use `use super::foo;` if you wish.

Comment: Hi, I believe there might have been some confusion because OP wasn't clear in the question. The `bar` module was declared in `lib.rs` and not in `main.rs`. 

Please see my answer to OP below for a more detailed response.

Comment: No, the OP edited the question and tried to fix it by: _Adding mod foo to main.rs fixes the issue_.

Comment: Actually never mind, I might have made a mistake myself 

Comment: Right it does appear that I was confused. Because OP was claiming that adding `mod bar` to `main.rs` solved the issue when in fact removing it is what will allow the code to compile since then `bar` will be properly declared as a module of `lib.rs` and `use crate::foo` can then properly refer to the `foo` module in `lib.rs`.

Comment: Your post is confusing in the end. You are referring a src/lib.rs in your Cargo.toml while it was already renamed to utils.rs...

Comment: @zrzka, thanks for this very details explanation, I create an example following the `Same package layout` part, still got the same error, https://github.com/videni/rust-package-layout-demo

Comment: Thanks, great answer.

I had a co-located main.rs + lib.rs and was trying to use `crate::my_pub_fn` notation, swapping to `[crate_name]::my_pub_fn` was what I needed :)

Answer (score 63):

In short [the official Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-01-packages-and-crates.html) has this to say:

> If a package contains `src/main.rs` and `src/lib.rs`, it has two crates: a library and a binary, both with the same name as the package.

Furthermore [the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#crate) says this:

> `crate` resolves the path relative to the current crate

So there are actually two crates in your project, and to which crate the `crate` qualifier resolves to depends on where you call it.

Now in your code example, if you want things to compile *you have to remove* `mod bar;` from `src/main.rs`. Otherwise you'll be declaring that `bar` is a module within two crates.

After you remove that, then because in `src/lib.rs` you had:

```
pub mod foo;
pub mod bar;
```

`bar` would now be a module within `src/lib.rs`'s crate, so the `crate` qualifier in `bar.rs` would then refer to `src/lib.rs`'s `hello-world` crate, which is what you want.

---

One more thing, if you wanted to access items that are exposed in `src/lib.rs` from `src/main.rs`, you have to do as @zrzka said, which is to name the name of the crate that both `src/lib.rs` and `src/main.rs` share. For example, in your project which is named `hello-world`:

```
use hello_world::foo;
fn main() {
    foo::say_foo();
}
```

is how you import the `foo` module declared  in `src/lib.rs` into `src/main.rs`.

However it does appear that the importing behavior doesn't work the other way. I.e. if you declare some public module in `src/main.rs`, you can't import it into the `src/lib.rs` crate even when you specify the name of the crate. I couldn't find documentation describing this behavior but by testing it in Rust 1.37.0, it does appear to be the case.

Answer (score 27):

The `lib.rs` and `main.rs` files are two independent entry points for your package.

When you use `cargo run` (or build the binary and run it explicitly), the entry point to be used is `main.rs`, and the `crate` keyword refer to the **binary crate**. It doesn't even have to know that there is something in `lib.rs`: the binary will treat the library as it would any other external crate, and it must be imported, through `extern crate hello_world` or, for example, `use hello_world::foo`.

When you import the library, however, the entry point is `lib.rs`, and the `crate` is the **library crate**. In this case, yes, all that you've added to `lib.rs` is exposed to the whole crate.

The usual worksflow in this case is to make the binary something like a thin wrapper around the library - in some extreme cases the `main.rs` would only contain something like

```
fn main() {
    library::main();
}
```

and the whole logic (and all the project structure) goes into the library crate. One of the reasons is exactly what you've run into: the possible confusion whether this concrete module is imported in each crate in the package.

Comment: This answer is very helpful. In other words, you can imagine that 1. `lib.rs` is really called `mod.rs`, 2. the folder `src` is really called `name_of_my_crate` as given by the `name` field of `Cargo.toml`'s `[package]` table, and 3. `main.rs` actually resides outside your crate (so you have to reference your crate by its name, not by `crate::`).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26946705/712526) shows a minimal, complete example of how to set up the Cargo.toml and the lib and bin so that the binary can use the library crate.

Answer (score 4):

(No new info here, but visualized)

| *Scenario* | independent | dependent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *Dependency Diagram* | [image: independent] | [image: dependent] |
| *main.rs* | `mod foo;` | `use hello::foo;` |
| *Explanation* | The two separate crate(-entry-point)s *main* & *lib* use the same source files, but *main* does not depend on *lib*. | The project consists mainly of a library, and *main* merely uses this library. *main* uses modules in this project through lib (for the most part). |
| *Evaluation* | Usually **not what one wants.** | This kind of **makes the project more modular**, and is usually what one imagines/wants to use. It also makes *main* a kind of integration-test for *lib*. This way, we are more likely to notice for example, if code in the library that should be accessible from the outside, is not. |

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: `mod` defines a new module in your crate, whether a binary crate or library crate; while `use` only brings the module into the current scope.

In your example, `use crate::foo` in `bar.rs` tries to bring a module named `foo` under crate root into scope. But because there is no `mod foo` in `main.rs`, the `foo` module is not part of the binary crate.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to have a bin project with name `app` if you want unit tests. `lib.rs` generates a lib crate, `main.rs` generate a bin crate, the bin crate just calls the lib crate.

- lib.rs

```rust
pub mod my_module;
```

- main.rs

```rust
use app::my_module::run;

fn main() {
   run();
}
```