# Unresolved import in Rust. Can't find crate

Tags: rust

I encountered this error when I try to use `use crate::some_module` but I can use `use my_package::some_module`. Anyone know why it works with the latter, but doesn't work with the first one?

Error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::some_module`

unresolved import
   help: a similar path exists: `my_package::some_module`
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "my_package"
//Bunch of other lines and dependencies
```

**lib.rs**

```
pub mod some_module;
//Bunch of other modules
```

Project structure:

```
my_package
|_src
  |_main.rs
  |_lib.rs
  |_some_module.rs

|_Cargo.toml
```

Comment: Upload the project to github if you can.

Comment: I can't. But also, I don't think that's necessary... Do you have any idea why I can use direct package name but not `crate`?

Comment: Relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57773297
The library (entry point `lib.rs`) and binary (entry point `main.rs`) are actually different crates. So `my_package` is an external library in `main.rs`, and can not be referred to as `crate::`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust modules confusion when there is main.rs and lib.rs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756927/rust-modules-confusion-when-there-is-main-rs-and-lib-rs)

Comment: Yes. Thank you! Rust modules concept is pretty unique, so I need to get use to it first, I guess.