# Cross-module function call in Rust

Tags: module, rust, code-organization, rust-crates

I'm trying to call a function belonging to some module from *another* module (for code factoring, organization, *etc*).

Here is my crate structure:

```
➜  mod_test git:(master) ✗ tree
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── bin
    │   └── one.rs
    ├── lib
    │   └── two.rs
    └── main.rs

3 directories, 5 files
```

In `main` I declare:

```
pub mod bin {
    pub mod one;
}
pub mod lib {
    pub mod two;
}
```

and all these files simply contain a trivial `pub fn main() {println!("hello");}`.

At this point, everything is *okay*.

### Now, **is it possible to call `lib::two::main` from `bin/one.rs`?**

None of `use crate::lib::two;`, `use super::lib::two;`, `use self::super::lib::two;` added in `bin/one.rs` work.

---

- edit: I have: `rustc 1.42.0 (b8cedc004 2020-03-09)` installed on Linux 5.3.0-45-generic, for what it's worth.
- edit 2: whenever using the `super` keyword, I get this mysterious error from `rustc`:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: there are too many leading `super` keywords
```

and I can't find any troubleshooting about this anywhere.

- edit 3: adding a `lib.rs` file in `src` declaring the `lib` module structure, and writing `use mod_test::lib::two;` in `one.rs` works, but:

  1) it defeats the idea of not multiplying "dumb module declaration files" in my crate.

  2) I have to literally copy the exact same information at two different places (in `main.rs` and in `lib.rs`)

  3) `use mod_test::lib::two;` is the only working syntax, using `crate` or `super` keywords still result in arcane compiler errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`src/bin` is a special directory name to Cargo. Files in this directory are compiled as standalone binaries when you run `cargo build`. When compiled as binaries, they aren't part of the crate structure defined in `main.rs` or `lib.rs`.

If you just want to use `bin::one` as a module inside `main.rs`, what you have works already! You're getting error messages from compiling `one.rs` as a standalone binary, not from compiling `main.rs` with `bin::one` as a module. If you run `cargo run --bin <name-of-project>`, compilation will succeed and it will run the program in `main.rs`.

To tell Cargo not to compile `one.rs` by itself, I would suggest renaming the `bin` directory. This not only solves the technical problem, but also is less likely to confuse other programmers reading the project, who will expect `bin` to contain binaries. There may be some way to prevent Cargo from treating `bin` specially in this way; however, renaming it is probably the best option.

If you *do* want `one.rs` to be compiled to a separate executable that uses `two`, you must create a `lib.rs` file in the same directory as `main.rs`. This is also a special file to Cargo and it defines the module structure for the library crate.

```
// lib.rs
pub mod lib { /* note: this lib is not related to lib.rs; just unfortunately named */
    pub mod two;
}
```

Then inside `one.rs`, write `use <crate-name>::lib::two;`

```
// bin/one.rs
use mod_test::lib::two;
```

`crate::lib::two` does **not** work, as files inside the `bin` directory are compiled as standalone binaries, not as crate members; therefore, you have to call the crate by its "external" name.

> adding a lib.rs file in src declaring the lib module structure, and writing use mod_test::lib::two; in one.rs works, but:
>
> 1) it defeats the idea of not multiplying "dumb module declaration files" in my crate.
>
> 2) I have to literally copy the exact same information at two different places (in main.rs and in lib.rs)

`main.rs` and `lib.rs` are **two different crate roots**. They are allowed to have different structure. You don't need both unless you want to generate both the binary and the library. If you want to *use* the library crate from inside any binary (including `main.rs`), it's just a `use` away:

```
use mod_test;
```

### See also

- [Rust modules confusion when there is main.rs and lib.rs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57756927/3650362)
- [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946646/3650362)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess that I was puzzled by the fact that creating a bin/ and lib/ results in two different crate roots.