# The trait `std::convert::From<cli::Opts>` is not implemented

Tags: rust, clap

I try to create a simple application parsing command line arguments using clap library and converting them to a `Config` custom structure. I implemented `From` trait for my structure, however, when I try to call `from` function, I receive the following error:

```
the trait bound `minimal_example::Config: std::convert::From<cli::Opts>` is not satisfied
the following implementations were found:
  <minimal_example::Config as std::convert::From<minimal_example::cli::Opts>>
required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

Here is the code:

**main.rs:**

```rust
mod cli;

use clap::Clap;
use minimal_example::Config;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let opts = cli::Opts::parse();
    let config = Config::from(opts);
}
```

**cli.rs:**

```rust
use clap::{Clap, crate_version};

/// This doc string acts as a help message when the user runs '--help'
/// as do all doc strings on fields
#[derive(Clap)]
#[clap(version = crate_version!(), author = "Yury")]
pub struct Opts {
    /// Simple option
    pub opt: String,
}
```

**lib.rs:**

```rust
mod cli;

pub struct Config {
    pub opt: String,
}

impl From<cli::Opts> for Config {
    fn from(opts: cli::Opts) -> Self {
        Config {
            opt: opts.opt,
        }
    }
}
```

**cargo.toml:**

```
[package]
name = "minimal_example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Yury"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
clap = {version="3.0.0-beta.2", features=["wrap_help"]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `mod cli` to both `lib.rs` and `main.rs`.

They are different from the standpoint of each other.

[Rust modules confusion when there is main.rs and lib.rs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756927/rust-modules-confusion-when-there-is-main-rs-and-lib-rs)
may help in understanding that.

That's what the error says. It's satisfied for `std::convert::From<minimal_example::cli::Opts>` but not for `std::convert::From<cli::Opts>`.

A simple fix:

**main.rs**

```rust
mod cli;
use clap::Clap;
use minimal_example::Config;

impl From<cli::Opts> for Config {
    fn from(opts: cli::Opts) -> Self {
        Config {
            opt: opts.opt,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let opts = cli::Opts::parse();
    let config = Config::from(opts);
}
```

Now `std::convert::From<cli::Opts>` is implemented for `Config`.

How you actually want to place all this depends on your package architecture.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the issue! I've implemented the `From` trait in the `cli.rs` module, and now it works! It seems to me that logically implementing it in the `main.rs` is not a good idea. However, your hint to the issue is right!

Comment: Logically, it might be more correct to not declare `mod cli` in main.rs as all, but export it from lib.rs instead, by either `pub mod cli` or `pub use cli::Opts`.