# how to understand mod xxx in lib.rs when using siblings

Tags: rust

In many posts, as in [sibling dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756927/rust-modules-confusion-when-there-is-main-rs-and-lib-rs#) people suggest to use `mod xxx` or even `pub mod xxx` in `lib.rs` when they are at the same level under root, I tried it too.

`src/lib.rs`:

```rust
pub mod printer;
pub mod screen;
```

`src/printer.rs`:

```rust
pub fn says(a: &str) {
    println!("printer says {}",a);
}
```

`src/screen.rs`:

```rust
use crate::printer;

pub fn says(b: &str) {
    printer::says("hi");
    println!("screen says {}", b);
}
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
mod printer;
mod screen;

fn main() {
    printer::says("hi");
    screen::says("hi");
}
```

The above worked, until I tried different `lib.rs` and I found that, when `lib.rs` is

```
pub mod screen;
```

the error is:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::printer`
 --> src\screen.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use crate::printer;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `printer` in the root
```

Actually, `lib.rs` can have both or neither mod screen and printer or only printer; if only it is not only screen.

Comment: Is this project a library or an executable? Technically, it _can_ be both, but this isn't usually what newcomers to Rust are intending when they add both a `lib.rs` and a `main.rs`..

Comment: @PeterHall both. I was studying Diesel demo. It has 1 binary, and 3 for library. But it was for Rust 2015. I was trying to change it to Rust 2018, and stuck at the path >.<. Then I started to study path, and got confused at `mod a; mod b` in `lib.rs`