# Cannot import modules in lib.rs

Tags: rust

I'm creating an application in Rust. The problem is that I cannot import a module inside `lib.rs` file and I wonder how am I supposed to do that.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
src/
├─ lib.rs
├─ main.rs
├─ app.rs
```

Inside `main.rs` file I use `mod lib` to use the library's public functions. But inside `lib.rs` file I would like to get the public methods from `app.rs` file, but unlike in other files, I cannot because of a compiler error:

```
file not found for module `app`

help: to create the module `app`, create file "src\lib\app.rs" or "src\lib\app\mod.rs"rustc(E0583)
```

Strangely enough, when I move the `app.rs` file to newly created `lib/app.rs`, the compiler would like to find the file in the previous location, which is `src/app.rs`, nor `src/lib/app.rs`. It gives me a headache.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Having both `lib.rs` and `main.rs` in the same project has some very specific implications and is generally not advised. Here is more information on what is happening and how it can be avoided: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756927/rust-modules-confusion-when-there-is-main-rs-and-lib-rs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do not** write `mod lib;`, with that name in particular. While this is technically valid code, it results in your code being compiled **twice**, under different configurations:

- `cargo` sees `lib.rs`, and tells `rustc` to compile a library with that as the “crate root”.

  - Under this condition, `mod app;` looks for a sibling file and succeeds.
- `cargo` sees `main.rs`, and tells `rustc` to compile a binary with that as the crate root.

  - `rustc` reads `main.rs` and sees `mod lib;`, so it compiles `lib.rs` *again* as a module inside of the binary.
  - Then, submodules of modules are expected to be in subdirectories, which is why it's asking for `src/lib/app.rs`.

If you are intending to define a library crate (which can be depended on by other packages, or your own integration tests and examples separate from `main`), then instead of `mod lib;`, just write paths referring to the library: `use foo::app::some_fn_in_app_rs;`, where `foo` is whatever name is specified in your `Cargo.toml`'s `[package]` section, because that's the name of the library. The library is automatically made available to the binary.

On the other hand, if you *don't* have any need for a library, then you can just declare modules starting from `main`. In that case, **don't name any of the modules `lib`.** Any name that's not `lib` or `main` is fine.

In either case, you can always move the code around later if your needs change. The only thing that is problematic is when you name a module [one of the filenames that means something specific to Cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html).