# How to build a Rust binary executable

Tags: rust, module, executable

I am trying to build a single Rust binary executable. In the src directory I have four files:

main.rs:

```
use fasta_multiple_cmp::get_filenames;

fn main() {
    get_filenames();
}
```

mod.rs:

```
pub mod fasta_multiple_cmp;

pub mod build_sequences_matrix;
```

fasta_multiple_cmp.rs:

```
pub mod fasta_multiple_cmp {

...

    pub fn get_filenames() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    ...
```

build_sequences_matrix.rs:

```
pub mod build_sequences_matrix {

    use simple_matrix::Matrix;
    ...
```

Cargo told me:

src/main.rs:3:5
|
3 | use fasta_multiple_cmp::get_filenames;
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `fasta_multiple_cmp

I believed I understood some little things, but ther I'm lost. What is going on?

Thaks for any hint!

Comment: Don't put the `pub mod` stuff in your `fasta_multiple_cmp.rs` and `build_sequences_matrix.rs`. Also I'm not sure about this, but you might have to move the `pub mod fasta_multiple_cmp;` from `mod.rs` to `main.rs`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it is built.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust modules confusion when there is main.rs and lib.rs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756927/rust-modules-confusion-when-there-is-main-rs-and-lib-rs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original code wasn't working because Rust's `use` is looking for a crate to import from, not just a file in the same directory.

If you want to separate logic into other files, you will need to break apart your project into both a binary and into a library (aka - a crate that your binary can use for imports).

This can be done in your `Cargo.toml` as:

```
[package]
edition = "2018"
name = "my_project"
version = "1.2.3"

... your other settings ...

[[bin]]
edition = "2018"
name = "whatever_name_for_binary"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

This means that your binary will be compiled into a file called "whatever_name_for_binary" in your `target` folder. It also means your non-binary files act as a library, and can be imported by your binary by using `use my_project::some_module;`

Because your project will now contain both a library and binary, you will need to specify when you want to run/compile the binary.

You do this by running: `cargo run --bin whatever_name_for_binary`

For more information, see the [Rust Book's Chapter on Modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html).