# UseDeclaration cannot find struct in the crate root

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I start with the `cargo new tst`. Then in the `src/lib.rs` I have:

```
pub struct Config {}
```

And `src/main.rs` looks like the following:

```
use crate::Config;

fn main() {}
```

This however does not compile:

```
> cargo run
   Compiling tst v0.1.0 (/home/*/rust/book/tst)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::Config`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use crate::Config;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Config` in the root

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `tst` due to previous error
```

But if I replace `crate::` with the name of the crate like so:

```
use tst::Config;

fn main() {}
```

Then it just work:

```
> cargo run
   Compiling tst v0.1.0 (/home/*/rust/book/tst)
warning: unused import: `tst::Config`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use tst::Config;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: `tst` (bin "tst") generated 1 warning
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.25s
     Running `target/debug/tst`
```

The output for `rustc --explain E0432` has the following quote, which if I understand it correctly means, that I can either *use the name of a crate* or simply `crate::`:

> In Rust 2018, paths in `use` statements are relative to the current module
> unless they begin with the name of a crate or a literal `crate::`, in which
> case they start from the crate root. As in Rust 2015 code, the `self::` and
> `super::` prefixes refer to the current and parent modules respectively.

Am I doing something wrong in here? Is there a way to use code from `lib.rs` without hardcoding the name of the crate?

```
> rustc --version
rustc 1.56.1 (Arch Linux rust 1:1.56.1-3)

> cat Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "tst"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

Comment: Hello, is because main.rs and lib.rs in the same package is like two crates. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756927/rust-modules-confusion-when-there-is-main-rs-and-lib-rs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust modules confusion when there is main.rs and lib.rs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756927/rust-modules-confusion-when-there-is-main-rs-and-lib-rs)

Comment: @orlp it doesn't, you can see I know I can use crate's name if I want to `use` stuff from the `lib.rs`, however I'm asking if there's a way/workaround/hack/whatever not to hardcode the name of the `crate` in `main.rs`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to refer to “the library crate in my package”; you must refer to it by its name. The Rust compiler doesn't (currently) know anything about other crates that happen to be in the same *Cargo package;* it just compiles one crate at a time.

In order for this to change, you would need to write a Rust RFC, which would need to include a description of why it would be valuable to have this feature — probably a stronger argument than “it would be less hardcoded”, since `main` depending on the library is almost certainly going to use library-specific names anyway, so the name of the library itself is a minor issue (unless, I suppose, you're creating many packages from a common template).