# Rust bin accessing modules

Tags: rust

#### Problem

Cannot access `ServerConnection` which is in `/src/gameclient/server_connection.rs` from `/src/bin/client.rs`.

I dont have any `lib.rs` nor `main.rs` all binaries are in `/src/bin/`

#### Project structure

[image]

#### `Cargo.toml`

```ini
...
[[bin]]
name = "server"
path = "src/bin/server.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "client"
path = "src/bin/client.rs"
...
```

#### `/src/gameclient/mod.rs`

rust-analyzer already complains here with:

> file not included in module tree

```rust
pub mod player_instance;
pub use crate::gameclient::player_instance::PlayerInstance;

pub mod server_connection;
pub use crate::gameclient::server_connection::ServerConnection;
```

#### `/src/gameclient/server_connection/ServerConnection`

```rust
...
pub struct ServerConnection {
    pub server_endpoint: url::Url,
}

pub impl ServerConnection {
    pub fn connect(&self) {
...
```

Comment: When i add a `lib.rs` with `pub mod gameclient;` it works. So is a `lib.rs` always required in such cases?

Comment: You need to have `mod gameclient` somewhere, whether that be in `bin/client.rs` with a [`#[path =]` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute) or in a `lib.rs` that gets used in `bin/client.rs`. Generally a crate will have a `lib.rs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pitaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847382/pitaj) gave the correct answer already.

Just for completeness.

#### /src/bin/client.rs

adding this at the very top makes me get rid of lib.rs.

```rust
#[path = "../gameclient/mod.rs"]
mod gameclient;
```

Comment: It is unclear why you wanted to avoid having a library (using `lib.rs`) in the first place. In the event that a module is used in multiple binaries, this approach would replicate the library modules to each one of them.

Comment: I was desparte and did not understand the [Module doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute).
Now i think a cleaner solution would be to have 3 separate Cargo.toml subprojects.
client, server, and sharedlibs and the main will just container the README.md with the project documentation.

Comment: There are much better resources for learning how the module system works: the book has an entire [chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html) on it. See also these other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946646/package-with-both-a-library-and-a-binary https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756927/rust-modules-confusion-when-there-is-main-rs-and-lib-rs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388861/how-can-i-include-a-module-from-another-file-from-the-same-project