# main can't find lib

Tags: rust

I've been trying to follow [Rust modules confusion when there is main.rs and lib.rs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756927/rust-modules-confusion-when-there-is-main-rs-and-lib-rs) but without success

My Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "wasm_jd"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
```

src/lib.rs

```
use serde_json::json;
use serde_json::Value;
use Value::*;

pub fn preview(contracted: Vec<&str>, json: Value) -> Value {
    // contracted is read only in the rest of the code
    convert(&contracted, "", &json)
}
...
```

src/main.rs

```
use serde_json::json;
use serde_json::Value;
use wasm_jd::preview;

fn main() {
    let j: Value = json!({"a": 1});
    let tmp: Value = preview(Vec::new(), j);
    let d = tmp.to_string();
    println!("{}", d)
}
```

When I do `cargo run` I get

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `wasm_jd`
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use wasm_jd::preview;
  |     ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `wasm_jd`
```

As far as I can see the names match up correctly so I'm very confused?

Comment: That changes the error to `1 | use crate::preview; no 'preview' in the root`. I tried `use crate::lib::preview` with a similar error

Comment: When I paste the code you posted into a new fresh directory, this compiles just fine (after adding dependencies and creating a stub for `convert`). Maybe there's something else wrong with it, can you paste the output of running `tree` or `exa -T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package is named `wasm_jd`. Typical configuration for building to WebAssembly is for `Cargo.toml` to have

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

This configuration will cause the error you see, because the compiler is being instructed to build a dynamic library not usable as a Rust dependency.

If you no longer need it, remove it. If you want *both* builds, specify that:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["lib", "cdylib"]
```

(The `lib` type is the default if no crate-type is specified.)

Once you do this, your original code,

```rust
use wasm_jd::preview;
```

should succeed.

Comment: Thanks. I made that change and now have `let tmp: Value = lib::preview(Vec::new(), j); ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module 'lib'`

Comment: @SimonH That's because the library is called `wasm_jd`, not `lib`. Your original code in the question was correct.