# rust modules resolution from main.rs

Tags: rust

I have a question about rust modules resolution.
It seems to be that inside crate modules I can reference the other modules using crate name or `crate`/`super`/`self` keywords.
but in `main.rs` I can only use modules with crate name?

Am I doing something stupid here?

My project:

```
$ tree
.
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── add2.rs
    ├── add.rs
    ├── lib.rs
    └── main.rs
```

`Cargo.toml` content:

```
[package]
name = "example"
....
```

`main.rs` content:

```
use example::add::{add_one};
fn main() {
    println!("{}", add_one(1));
}
```

`lib.rs` content:

```
pub mod add;
```

`add.rs` content:

```
pub fn add_one(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x + 1
}
```

`add2.rs` content:

```
use crate::add::{add_one};

pub fn add_two(x: i32) -> i32 {
    add_one(add_one(x))
}
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946646/rust-package-with-both-a-library-and-a-binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing something stupid here?

No, it`s just that Cargo adds one more layer of complexity called the "package", for better or worse, which makes it more confusing.

In short, your Cargo package contains two Rust crates: the binary one and the library one. When you are in `main.rs`, the `example` library crate is an external dependency like any other... which means you aren`t in the same crate!

Comment: I was following the book https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65735609/rust-modules-resolution-from-main-rs/65735926#65735926 and modules/crates was quite confusing...

Comment: Yeah, it`s one of the worst parts of the book. I have been programming for decades, over a dozen languages, and it still managed to confuse me too.

Answer (score 0):

Crate roots such as `main.rs`, `lib.rs`, `bin/other_root.rs`, etc. are treated differently by the module system. When they refer to module files they are referring to files in the root of the `src/` directory only. In the normal case `mod` refers to files in the root of a local sub-directory with the same name as the containing file, mirroring the unique container constraint of the inline module layout as well as the file system hierarchy (barring linked files, of course). In essence, crate roots treat `src/` as their local sub-directory as far as `mod` is concerned.

[I gave perhaps a more wordy explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70269877/1612190)