# Rust use vs mod?

Tags: rust, import, include

I'm struggling to wrap my head around these,

- `use` declaration

  > A *use declaration* creates one or more local name bindings synonymous with some other path. Usually, a `use` declaration is used to shorten the path required to refer to a module item. These declarations may appear in modules and blocks, usually at the top.

And,

- `mod` item

  > A *module item* is a module, surrounded in braces, named, and prefixed with the keyword `mod`. A module item introduces a new, named module into the tree of modules making up a crate. Modules can nest arbitrarily.

Basically, when I go to layout my module, I believe I know how I want it layed out but [I get confused about how these two things should be layered and what they do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66916893/124486). I would think only one of the two would include code?

Comment: In short: `mod` means "here's the new module (from file or in curly brackets), store it for future use", `use` means "there's already created module, pull it from this path and let me use it here".

Answer (score 34):

Consider you have a module `my_mod` with a pub function `my_func`. You can't `use` this function in your crate (or outside your crate) until you include your module using `mod my_mod` statement.

After you include your module, you can use your function like that:

```
mod my_mod;

...
my_mod::my_func(...)
...
```

You can't use `my_mod::my_func` statement if you don't include your module somewhere in your crate.

Sometimes it is better to import frequently used definitions:

```
mod my_mod;
use my_mod::my_func;
```

Now, if you want to use your function, you can just write:

```
my_func(...);
```

You can also re-export definitions of sub-modules (or even other crates!) using `pub use` statement.

If you working with other crates imported through `Cargo.toml` (by listing them as dependencies), you may import definitions from these crates using only `use` statement.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, so as I understand, the keyword "use" is like the use namespace of other languages like c# or c++?

Comment: Why do you need `mod` if there is `use`?

Comment: @Alper you cant `use` the module in another .rs file if the module is not `mod`-ed

Answer (score 17):

The language documentation tries but misses a few important concepts implied by `mod` and I have had to do test to figure this out. To try an save others the time I offer the following conclusions...

1. The module system hierarchy forms a **source tree** similar to a file system directory wherein `mod` selects an immediate child modules relative to its host module. Importantly, **these module files referenced by `mod` are required to be held inside a sub-directory that is (1) within the same directory as the host module file and (2) that sub-directory must have the same name as the host module file.** That means modules cannot import sibling, parents, grandchildren, or cousin modules. *The apparent exception to this hierarchical containment pattern and perhaps the source of much confusion are the root modules (`main.rs`, `lib.rs`). These particular module files do occur within `src/` alongside their sub-modules; however, they are special. Specifically, these **crate root module files (`main.rs`, `lib.rs`, `bin/other_root.rs`) are actually treated as parent modules to the `src/` directory itself.** (As such, at compile time they treated as being named either `/src.rs` with an associated sub-directory `/src/` or (better yet) as the root module, `src/mod.rs`, within the `src/` directory itself).
2. The crate root modules (and also `Cargo.toml`) constructs a **source tree** by selecting modules in the root of the `src/` directory. These modules may then include a selection from their associated module sub-directories, then those modules from their associated module sub-directories, and so on. The resultant tree of included module files becomes the source code available in the crate. Importantly, crate roots modules (`lib.rs`, `main.rs`, `bin/other_crate_root.rs`) may actually select different initial modules from the `/src' directory and thereby evolve a different tree of modules.
3. Finally, once a module does exist within the **source tree** of a crate it may be referred to by its path (depending on visibility constraints). In particular, the `use` statement may now be used to abbreviate the path to the module and/or its externally visible contents.

Comment: Are you sure about the "only being able to import immediate child modules" part? It seems possible using `crate::` or `super::` (what I'd call "absolute" and "relative" imports respectively).

Comment: `use` is different from `mod`. `use` provides for the abbreviation references to contents of the source tree. `mod` establishes the source tree.

Answer (score 16):

`mod` keyword is like `import` statement. You bring the content from outside file to be accessible. Rust needs to know about the existence of the module. (For external dependencies specified in Cargo.toml, Rust and Cargo allows you to use their items directly without manually declaring each crate.)

```
 // another_file is the name of the file, another_file.rs
 // file name is default module
 mod another_file
```

Now you brought the content. `use` is used to create a path top-level so you could use a function or struct in multiple parts. Let's say you have to reach a struct deep inside the module:

```
// mod could be in the same file: my_game::education::learning_rust::Person;
// in main.rs you dont need to use `use crate::another_file`. you would use `use crate` if you were in other module
use another_file::my_game::education::learning_rust::Person;
```

With `use` declaration, we are bringing the `Person` into the scope.

then inside `main`

```
fn main(){
    let person=Person::new()
    person.display_info();
    }
```

If I did not use `use` keyword, everwhere I needed `Person` struct I would write this:

```
let person=another_file::my_game::education::learning_rust::Person::new()
```

- Also if you want to access standard library features, you use `use`

  ```
  use std::net;
  use std::io::prelude::*;
  ```

Comment: What's the relationship between the `mod` statement in your example and the `mod` declaration for an actual module...? So if I have a file named `a.rs`, then inside `a.rs` I define a module like so `pub mod a`. I want to use the functions from `a.rs` in main, so do I _still_ need a _second_ `mod a` statement in main?

Answer (score 3):

The **mod** statement tells the compiler about a file it hasn't seen before. The **use** statement lets you import things the compiler already knows about into the local scope.