# Rust: no `module` in the root

Tags: import, rust

When I run `use crate::feed;` in `src/cmdline.rs`  I expect that to import `src/feed.rs`, but it doesn't. Instead I get,

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::feed`
 --> src/cmdline.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use crate::feed;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ no `feed` in the root
```

Despite the fact that `src/feed.rs` exists. However, if I panic and change it to `mod feed;` then I get

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `feed`
 --> src/cmdline.rs:2:1
  |
2 | mod feed;
  | ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: to create the module `feed`, create file "src/cmdline/feed.rs"
```

Using `mod super::`

```
error: expected identifier, found keyword `super`
 --> src/cmdline.rs:2:5
  |
2 | mod super::feed;
  |     ^^^^^ expected identifier, found keyword
```

Or with `use super::`

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::feed`
 --> src/cmdline.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use super::feed;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ no `feed` in the root
```

File structure for files in question looks like this,

```
src/feed.rs
src/cmdline.rs
src/main.rs
```

Comment: does `src/feed.rs` exist ? in `src/lib.rs` (or `main.rs`) do you have `mod feed;`

Comment: @prog-fh updated.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to make my imports work the way you describe by doing the following.

First in `main.rs` I import the module `cmdline` and each module I want to be able to use via `crate::`.

```rust
// file src/main.rs
mod cmdline;
mod feed; // <== import module to be able to use via `crate::feed`

fn main() {
  cmdline::do_something();
}
```

Then in `cmdline.rs` I use `create::feed`.

```rust
// file src/cmdline.rs

use crate::feed; // <== import sibling module

pub fn do_something() {
  feed::do_something_else();
}
```

And my `feed.rs` looks something like this.

```rust
// file src/feed.rs
pub fn d_something_else() {
  // ...
}
```

From what I understand from experimenting is that you need to first use `mod` in your `main.rs` to define which modules are included in your crate.

Comment: Excellent, none of the other answers I read about this problem stated that so clearly.

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out. The rust module system doesn't permit importing sibling files,

- `src/a.rs`
- `src/b.rs`

Full stop: `a.rs` can not import `b.rs`. What it will do is try to source it from

- `src/a/b.rs`

If you're on this answer, none of this probably makes sense to you and you've wasted hours on this. This was a source of my confusion:

- `src/main.rs`

Is actually special. Inside `src/main.rs` a `mod` will import a sibling file, (and also with the now deprecated `mod.rs`; or, with `lib.rs`). But the point is that your own rust files can't make use of rust code in sibling files.

Comment: `main.rs` is not special in that sense. Rust builds a module hierarchy with the provided `mod _;` usages. When you try to `use crate::feed`, it looks into `main` module (since it's the crate root), and checks if a module named `feed` is connected to it. Since it's not (as you didn't include the `mod feed;` in main.rs), the compiler errors out.

I will say that though the module system is very clear and not that hard (only initially) to understand, the explicit creation of module hierarchy has not been of use to me till date, as I just mimic the actual file hierarchy.