# How do you set up a directory structure for a bunch of small Rust programs?

Tags: rust, project-structure

I don't really know Rust yet, but I have a project that I want to contain a bunch of small Rust programs with a file of a few functions that can be used in all the programs.

I can't seem to get it to be able to see the `utils.rs` file with this specific structure.

directory tree:

```
rust_stuff
|
|_ Cargo.lock
|_ Cargo.toml
|_ src/
|  |_ bin/
|     |_ project1.rs
|     |_ project2.rs
|     |_ ...more projects...
|
|_ utils.rs  // file of functions to use in all programs
```

In `project1.rs` I have tried `use crate::utils;` and also `use utils::func1;` and neither seems to be able to find it. Also, the functions in `utils.rs` are public. And I've tried a `mod.rs` file containing `pub mod utils;` and that didn't seem to do anything.

Is it possible to have this structure? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the linked answer says: ***Don't**. Put all of your source code into the src directory*. You probably want a [workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html). See also [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946646/155423)

Comment: You can use the library crate in your package for the common code, i.e. add the common code to `src/lib.rs` and import it using `use package_name::…`.