# Unresolved imports when I move a binary crate to src/bin

Tags: rust, compilation, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have a Rust project with the following structure:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── main.rs
    ├── generator.rs
    └── lib.rs
```

With the following code in lib.rs and main.rs respectively:

```
# lib.rs
pub mod generator
```

```
# main.rs
use clap::{Parser, Subcommand};
use mypackage::generator;
```

The above builds. However, I want to create another binary crate in the same package and I read [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-01-packages-and-crates.html) that multiple binary crates can be crated in the `src/bin` directory. But when I move the `main.rs` file as `check.rs` in `src/bin`, leading to the directory as follows:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── bin
    │   └── check.rs
    ├── generator.rs
    └── lib.rs
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved imports `mypackage::generator`
 --> src/bin/check.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     generator::Generator,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^ could not find `generator` in `mypackage`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `clap`
 --> src/bin/check.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use clap::{Parser, Subcommand};
  |     ^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `clap`
```

- I did not change my Cargo.toml as it seems this should've worked as it is based on the answer on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26953326/7776212). Any clues as to why this is going wrong?
- More importantly, why is the binary crate not even able to resolve the `clap` package which is listed in Cargo.toml as a dependency too?

### Edit

This is what my `Cargo.toml` file looks like:

```
[package]
name = "mypackage"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
clap = {version = "4.1.8", features = ["derive"], optional = true}
dot = {version = "0.1.4", optional = true}
enumset = "1.0.12"
inkwell = {version = "0.1.1", features = ["llvm15-0"], optional = true}
itertools = "0.10.5"
lalrpop-util = "0.19.8"
once_cell = "1.17.1"
rayon = "1.7.0"
regex = "1.7.1"
snailquote = "0.3.1"
strum = {version = "0.24.1", features = ["derive"]}
tracing = "0.1.37"
tracing-subscriber = {version = "0.3.16", features = ["env-filter"]}

[build-dependencies]
lalrpop = "0.19.9"

[features]
default = []
generate = []
bin = ["generate", "dep:clap"]
```

And I am running a simple `cargo build` to build my package.

Comment: Did you make the necessary changes to `Cargo.toml` (i.e. `[[bin]]` sections?)

Comment: So this answer on another post seems to say that Cargo.toml changes are not needed since I'm putting it in src/bin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26953326/7776212

Comment: It works for me without changes to Cargo.toml.

Comment: Can you show us you `Cargo.toml`? Also try to remove your `target` folder and rebuild, just in case.

Comment: The errors seem _as if_ the `src/bin/check.rs` is getting compiled under a different `Cargo.toml`. There's no reason that should happen; I concur that more information is needed. In addition to the `Cargo.toml`, show us exactly what commands you're running.

Comment: I have added the `Cargo.toml` file as an edit now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `clap` declared as an optional dependency.

```rust
[dependencies]
clap = {version = "4.1.8", features = ["derive"], optional = true}

[features]
default = []
generate = []
bin = ["generate", "dep:clap"]
```

So, `clap` won't be available to use except when you `cargo build --features bin`. Presumably the `generate` feature is also related to the missing `generator` module.

(There is no difference between `src/main.rs` and `src/bin/check.rs` for this purpose, so you must have changed the enabled features or something as well as moving the file.)

If you want your binary to only be built in that case, so it doesn't error otherwise, you can declare `required-features`:

```rust
[[bin]]
name = "check"
required-features = ["bin"]
```

This will still require you to pass `--features` to build or run the `check` binary, but you won't get a compilation error when you don't; the bin target will be skipped.

(There is a proposal for [automatically enabling features when the target needing them is being built](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3374), but it isn't accepted or implemented yet.)

Comment: Yes, using the `[[bin]]` along with the cargo command you mentioned works for me now. Thanks!